# Prove or disprove that if $f$ is differentiable on $\left[ a,b\right]$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\left[ a,b\right]$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My proof-trying.

Assume $f$ is differentiable on $\left[ a,b\right]$. I.e.,

$\lim _{x\rightarrow a^+}\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) } {x-a}$ and $\lim _{x\rightarrow b^-}\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( b\right) } {x-b}$ exist. **So, can you check my statements on my proof-trying and can you give a hint?**

Comment: What statements?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ means that in addition to the existence of the two limits you noted, the limit $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$ also exists, for any $c \in (a,b)$. I didn't notice any other statements to check.

Comment: @UmbertoP. If $f$ is differentiable on $\left[ a,b\right]$. then can we say 

$\lim _{x\rightarrow a^+}\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) } {x-a}$ and $\lim _{x\rightarrow b^-}\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( b\right) } {x-b}$ exist ? Actually, what is $f$  is differentiable on $[a,b]$ mean?

Comment: Yes, see @Bungo's comment.

Comment: Well, continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous...you do not need differentiability.

Comment: For a hint, you can proceed in two steps. (1) Show that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then it is continuous on $[a,b]$. (2) Show that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Bungo Assume $f$ is continuous on $\left[ a,b\right]$, i.e., for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that we have if $\left| x-a\right| <\delta$ then $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| <\epsilon$. We need to show that  if $a,b$ in the set and $\left| x-a\right|  <\delta$ then $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| <\epsilon$ but it is clear and $a,b$ in the set. Is it true for proof?

Comment: @UmbertoP. can you check my last comment?

Comment: @Kahler What do you mean by "$a,b$ in the set"? What set? Also note that what you wrote after "i.e." is precisely the condition for $f$ to be continuous at the point $a$, not on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Bungo I meant that if $f$ is uniformly continuos then for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $a,b\in X$ and $\left| x-a\right| <\delta$ then $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| <\varepsilon$. Note that in the question $X=\left[ a, b\right]$. Clearly, $a,b\in\left[ a, b\right]$. Is it true?

Comment: @Kahler I don't understand your argument. You seem to be using $a,b$ to mean two different things: the endpoints of the interval $[a,b]$, as well as two arbitrary elements of the interval. I suggest using different notation. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, then given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$, such that $|f(c) - f(d)| < \epsilon$ whenever $c,d$ are points in $[a,b]$ satisfying $|c-d| < \delta$.